# Removing dots and slashes when piping into new file in bash (awk)

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a bash question (when using `awk`). I'm extracting every single instance of the first and fifth column in a textfile and piping it to a new file with the following code,

```
cut -f4 test170201.rawtxt | awk '/stream_0/ { print $1, $5  }' > testLogFile.txt
```

This is part of the file (test170201.rawtxt) I'm extracting the data from, columns `Timestamp` and `Loss`,

```
Timestamp                 Stream     Status     Seq         Loss Bytes    Delay
17/02/01.10:58:25.212577  stream_0     OK      80281          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.213401  stream_0     OK      80282          0  1000     38472
17/02/01.10:58:25.215560  stream_0     OK      80283          0  1000     38473
17/02/01.10:58:25.216645  stream_0     OK      80284          0  1000     38472
```

This is the result I'm getting in testLogFile.txt

```
17/02/01.10:58:25.212577 0
17/02/01.10:58:25.213401 0
17/02/01.10:58:25.215560 0
17/02/01.10:58:25.216645 0
```

I want to get rid of the `"/"`, `":"` and the `"."`. The result output I want would look like this:

```
 170201 105825 212577 0
 170201 105825 213401 0
 170201 105825 215560 0
 170201 105825 216645 0
```

My question is, how do I modify my code to get the above result? The platform I'm using is Debian GNU/Linux and the GNU awk version is 4.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [awk `gsub()` (global substitute) function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gsub_0028_0029-function-1) to:

- substitute `.` with space
- remove `:` and `/`

```bash
cut -f4 test170201.rawtxt | awk '/stream_0/ { 
    gsub(/\./," ",$1)
    gsub(/[:\/]/, "", $1)
    print $1, $5
}' > testLogFile.txt
```

In fact, the `cut` seems to be redundant - this will do what you require with the example data:

```bash
awk '/stream_0/ { 
    gsub(/\./," ",$1)
    gsub(/[:\/]/, "", $1)
    print $1 , $5
}' test170201.rawtxt > testLogFile.txt
```

Comment: I used your first solution and changed it at the end to,  `cut -f4 test170201.rawtxt | awk '/stream_0/ { 
    gsub(/\./," ",$1)
    gsub(/[:\/]/, "", $1)
    print $1 , $5
}' > testLogFile.txt` And it worked, I use cut because I want the output to be a new file

Comment: @user3325598: You can do `awk '{awk program}' file_to_read >output_file` You do not need `cut` to do this.

Comment: @dawg: Oh ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No problem, this `sed` command in your pipe should do the trick:

```
  awk '/stream_0/ { print $1, $5  }' test170201.rawtxt |
  sed 's=/==g;s=:==g;s=\.= =g;s=^= =' > testLogFile.txt
```

Note that `.` is a regular expression, so you must escape it to get `sed` to recognize it as a period character.  The `g` modifier on the substitute commands tells `sed` to remove all occurrences. Finally, the '^' regular expression matches the start of the line; that last clause puts the leading space into the output.  The `cut` command appears to be redundant.

See `man sed` for more.

Comment: Yes I do! Will add it to the question, sorry! For some reason nothing happens when I type in your solution, I can still keep on writing code. It seems as there is missing something that ends your code.

Comment: The closing quote on the `sed` command did not match the opening quote.  Fixed now.

Comment: It worked now, however, It does not give me the spaces that I originally wanted (I've received one solution above) but since I need both solutions this turnes out to be perfect as well. Thank you.

Comment: I missed that requirement.  You can get that with this solution by replacing the dot with a space, instead of deleting it, and by adding a space to the start of the line.  I have adjusted my answer to do this, for completeness sake.  Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` in awk command before printing your columns:

```
awk '/stream_0/ { gsub(/[\/:]/, "", $1); gsub(/[.]/, " ", $1); print $1, $5 }' file

170201 105825 212577 0
170201 105825 213401 0
170201 105825 215560 0
170201 105825 216645 0
```